# How do I run an ASP.Net Core executable file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.Net Core.  I have been following a tutuorial.  I got to the point at which Javascript code was added to my project.  I ran my program, and nothing in the script worked.  After adding a few alert() calls, it was apparent that my program was not finding my script.  People here and at Reddit suggested I look at the network tab of DevTools.  I saw that my program was not able to find any js or css files.

Being an old-school C++/C# developer, I was running the program from a command window by going to the folder containing the executable file and typing the name of the file.

I went back to the beginning.  The tutorial directs me to use the dotnet command, which is brand new to me.  The first time it tells me to run my program, it tells me to go to the project directory and enter "dotnet run".  It just hit me like a ton of bricks that that was what I should have done the first time.  I went back to that project, used "dotnet run", and it worked.

So, my question is this:  is it possible to run MyProject.exe by itself?  If so, how?  Copy it into my project folder?  Or is the "dotnet run" command the standard way of executing an ASP.Net Core application?

Comment: There is nothing fancy. You just need to make sure your web app shows the right "content root path". I believe there are tons of previous discussions on that.

Comment: I've never heard of an ASP.Net executable, but I learn new things everyday. ASP.Net is a web programming language. It runs inside a web _server_. Java script runs inside a web _browser_ (client side). Java script not running is 100% a web browser issue and has nothing to do with .Net. The "standard way" to run ASP.Net is to compile and deply to a web server then run the app from within a browser. Being a C++ developer you must understand the importance of providing specific detail when trying to troubleshoot an issue. How did you create an EXE from ASP.Net code? What type of project is it?

Comment: In a console window, I went to my project's bin/debug folder.  I didn't see the executable there, but I found a netasp3.1 folder.  When I looked in there, I found a .exe file, and ran it.  When I was having problems, I got the finished code for the tutorial out of github.  It had a netasp2.0 folder, and there was no executable in it.  Only a DLL.  I learned that that was normal until ASP.Net Core 3.0, when an executable was also built.  I haven't yet learned what that gets built for.

Comment: I suggest you find a basic tutorial and follow it to the letter. You're getting mixed up here with thick client (.exe) applications and web applications (these can only run inside a web server). I can't think of any asp.net project where there is an EXE involved. If you can reference one of the pages you're referring to, perhaps I can clarify. Your question is too vague and does not provide any clues as to what you are really doing here.

Answer (score 0):

I think it won't work if you directly run it (not sure if we can run MVC project using dotnet-cli (dotnet run will try to load only MSIL to CLR)).
 
DotNet core console application is different from .net core MVC projects 
you can run your project by following ways. 
**1. Run using visual studio**
 when you create an MVC application, in the visual studio there will be multiple options to run it, you can choose IISexpress one, it will open in the default browser. 
for step by step guide -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-aspnet-core?view=vs-2019 
**2. publish it in IIS**
For this you need to ensure few things, like hosting bundle is installed or not, IIS is correctly configured for core application or not. 
for step by step guide -> https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/ 
**3. Use VSCode** 
for step by step guide -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vscode?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

The question is old and my answer is for .NET 6 and 7, but it may also work for older versions. You can technically run the .exe file by double clicking on it or from the command line. The exe file is basically a Kestrel console app host that listens to a port. The default ports are 5000 for http and 5001 for https. So, by running the exe file and see the icon in your taskbar, you can navigate to "http://localhost:5000" in your browser and should be able to see your home page.

But, how would you manage the life cycle? You need your host to run as a background service. You can use IIS on Windows or host it in a Windows Service. Here are some references:

[Host and deploy ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy)

[Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service)

[Configure endpoints for the ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints)

Comment: When I do that it doesn't provide static files from wwwroot for some reason. Any idea why?